# How to query TCP connection state in go?

Tags: tcp, go

On the client side of a TCP connection, I am attempting to to reuse established connections as much as possible to avoid the overhead of dialing every time I need a connection.  Fundamentally, it's connection pooling, although technically, my pool size just happens to be one.

I'm running into a problem in that if a connection sits idle for long enough, the other end disconnects.  I've tried using something like the following to keep connections alive:

```
err = conn.(*net.TCPConn).SetKeepAlive(true)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
err = conn.(*net.TCPConn).SetKeepAlivePeriod(30*time.Second)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
```

But this isn't helping.  In fact, it's causing my connections to close sooner.  I'm pretty sure this is because (on a Mac) this means the connection health starts being probed after 30 seconds and then is probed at 8 times at 30 second intervals.  *The server side must not be supporting keepalive*, so after 4 minutes and 30 seconds, the client is disconnecting.

There might be nothing I can do to keep an idle connection alive indefinitely, and that would be absolutely ok if there were some way for me to at least *detect* that a connection has been closed so that I can seamlessly replace it with a new one.  Alas, even after reading all the docs and scouring the blogosphere for help, I can't find any way at all in go to query the state of a TCP connection.

There must be a way.  Does anyone have any insight into how that can be accomplished?  Many thanks in advance to anyone who does!

**EDIT:**

Ideally, I'd like to learn how to handle this, low-level with pure go-- without using third-party libraries to accomplish this.  Of course if there is some library that does this, I don't mind being pointed in its direction so I can see how they do it.

Comment: Maybe I need to go ahead and write to the connection, then trap and analyze the error to see if redialing and writing again is advised?

Comment: You detect a closed tcp connection by reading from it, not writing. This is the same in any language, because it's how the underlying Berkeley sockets api works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The socket api doesn't give you access to the state of the connection. You can query the current state it in various ways from the kernel (`/proc/net/tcp[6]` on linux for example), but that doesn't make any guarantee that further sends will succeed.

> I'm a little confused on one point here. My client is ONLY sending data. Apart from acking the packets, the server sends nothing back. Reading doesn't seem an appropriate way to determine connection status, as there's noting TO read.

The socket API is defined such that that you detect a closed connection by a read returning 0 bytes. That's the way it works. In Go, this is translated to a Read returning `io.EOF`. This will usually be the fastest way to detect a broken connection.

> So am I supposed to just send and act on whatever errors occur? If so, that's a problem because I'm observing that I typically do not get any errors at all when attempting to send over a broken pipe-- which seems totally wrong

If you look closely at how TCP works, this is the expected behavior. If the connection is closed on the remote side, then your first send will trigger an RST from the server, fully closing the local connection. You either need to read from the connection to detect the close, or if you try to send again you will get an error (assuming you've waited long enough for the packets to make a round trip), like "broken pipe" on linux.

> To clarify... I can dial, unplug an ethernet cable, and STILL send without error. The messages don't get through, obviously, but I receive no error

If the connection is actually broken, or the server is totally unresponsive, then you're sending packets off to nowhere. The TCP stack  can't tell the difference between packets that are *really* slow, packet loss, congestion, or a broken connection. The system needs to wait for the retransmission timeout, and retry the packet a number of times before failing. The standard configuration for retries alone can take between 13 and 30 minutes to trigger an error.

What you can do in your code is

- Turn on keepalive. This will notify you of a broken connection more quickly, because the idle connection is always being tested.
- Read from the socket. Either have a concurrent Read in progress, or check for something to read first with select/poll/epoll (Go usually uses the first)
- Set timeouts (deadlines in Go) for everything.

If you're not expecting any data from the connection, checking for a closed connection is very easy in Go; dispatch a goroutine to read from the connection until there's an error.

```
notify := make(chan error)

go func() {
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        n, err := conn.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            notify <- err
            return
        }
        if n > 0 {
            fmt.Println("unexpected data: %s", buf[:n])
        }
    }
}()
```

Comment: I really want to say thank you for all your help.  You've done a lot to improve my understanding of how all of this works.  I really do think you're steering me in the right direction.  With all of that being said, the code snippet you gave only seems to detect the case where the other end has hung up.  That hasn't been my concern so much as the case where it is a network problem interfering with the connection.  Unplugging a network cable, for instance, doesn't cause the code above to detect that the connection is no longer viable.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @KentRancourt: I'm not sure what else I can add; **this is how tcp works**.  If there's a network problem, tcp is designed to accept you data, and keep trying to get it to it's destination. If you want to send data to a server, and be assured that it was processed, you _must_ have an application-level acknowledgment. If you have that, then you can specify a time limit to wait before declaring the connection broken. Short of changing your protocol, you can only make a best effort to send the packets and hope they arrive.

Comment: thanks again. I'm accepting your answer. You've been incredibly helpful. fwiw, I'm not in control of the remote end of the connection, so sending an app-level ack isn't possible. One final question: if it all works as you describe (and I have no doubt it does), and a broken connection really isn't detectable for many minutes of retries and acks not being received, that means the sender can be barfing packets into the ether for several minutes. Doesn't that, in some respect, contradict the notion of guaranteed delivery? Is there some way to know sooner if a packet can't be delivered?

Comment: @KentRancourt: "guaranteed delivery" is at a lower layer than your application logic, and doesn't even mean that the payload reaches the remote application, just that the tcp stack ACK'ed it. Like I said before, you can't distinguish between delayed packets or lost packets (due to error or congestion), so all TCP can do to "guarantee delivery" is continue to retry and wait for some extended period of time. If you send enough to fill your window size, sending will block, and that's where setting a write deadline will help break the connection.

Answer (score 2):

- There is no such thing as 'TCP connection state', by design. There is only what happens when you send something. There is no TCP API, at any level down to the silicon, that will tell you the current state of a TCP connection. You have to try to use it.
- If you're sending keepalive probes, the server doesn't have any choice but to respond appropriately. The server doesn't even know that they are keepalives. They aren't. They are just duplicate ACKs. Supporting keepalive just means supporting *sending* keepalives.

Comment: thank you for your response.  How is it that netstat, for instance, can show me connection state such as ESTABLISHED or CLOSE_WAIT if there's no way at all of querying connection state?

Comment: @KentRancourt: you can get that info from the kernel. On linux netstat parses `/proc/net/tcp[6]`. That does you no good in your program though, because that state can change as soon as you try to use the socket. You `recv` if you want to see if there's data or it's closed, you `send` if you want to see if the network responds, and you use a timeout if you don't want either of those to take an undetermined amount of time.

Comment: @JimB thank you for the pointers.  I'm a little confused on one point here.  My client is ONLY sending data.  Apart from acking the packets, the server sends nothing back.  Reading doesn't seem an appropriate way to determine connection status, as there's noting TO read.  So am I supposed to just send and act on whatever errors occur?  If so, that's a problem because I'm observing that I typically do not get any errors at all when attempting to send over a broken pipe-- which seems totally wrong.

Comment: To clarify... I can dial, unplug an ethernet cable, and STILL send without error.  The messages don't get through, obviously, but I receive no error.

Comment: @KentRancourt: I made a full answer, since it was too much to describe in the comments.

Comment: @KentRancourt Remember that a connection state is momentary/transient. You could query the connection state, and in the nano seconds later when you want to send a message on the connection, the connection could been broken. There are a lot of cases where the connection can be broken, but your application(or the TCP stack of your OS) will not know that fact until you send a message and wait until TCP times it out because of a lack of ACKs from the other side. Sending a message on a broken connection and not getting an error(until later) is normal. The error manifests itself later on.

Comment: @nos that helps a bit.  This is the farthest I've ever dived into TCP.  Clearly, I need to read up more when time permits.  In most languages (go included), when you write over a TCP connection, you immediately get back a count of how many bytes were written and if there was an error it's either returned or an exception is thrown/raised.  I guess I have allowed that to mislead me into thinking that any packet sent this way with all signs pointing to success _was_ actually successful.  I see now that is not the case.  I'm going to look farther into JimB's answer below.

Comment: @KentRancourt Sending on TCP is not done synchronously. You hand off a buffer of data to the TCP stack. The count you get back says how many bytes were copied into that buffer. The TCP stack then takes over and asynchronously tries to deliver the data. e.g. if you unplug the network cable, obviously data cannot be delivered. But TCP will try for a while, until its timers expire. if you plug the cable back in, TCP might deliver the data just fine. This means send() could succeed even if the other end was just nuked, since TCP will try for a while to deliver the data you handed over to TCP.

Comment: @KentRancourt ESTABLISHED, CLOSE_WAIT etc are *port* states, not connection states, and they are looked up in the kernel, or via SNMP. For example, a local port in CLOSE_WAIT would be in FIN_WAIT_1 at the other end => not a connection state. Re sending, once you have enough pending send data that is unacknowledged due to the cable pull *and* TCP has been trying long enough to send it that it has timed out, *then* you will get a connection reset.